# how to override ExternalLinkForm

Tags: sitecore-client

I need to override some code inside of `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.ExternalLink.ExternalLinkForm.`

I created class based on   `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.ExternalLink.ExternalLinkForm.`
Define it at 
`~/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/ExternalLink/ExternalLink.xml`. but when I try to open External link dialog (click on insert external link at link field) I see an error:

```
CodeBeside class "Loreal.Project.Loreal.ExternalLink.LCorpExternalLinkForm, Loreal.Project.Corporate" not found. (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: CodeBeside class
"Loreal.Project.Loreal.ExternalLink.LCorpExternalLinkForm,
Loreal.Project.Corporate" not found. (method:
Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

  [Exception: CodeBeside class "MyExternalLinkForm, MyProject" not found. 
  (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).]
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +133
        Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.CreateCodeBeside(String type) +113
        Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e) +238
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +173
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +380
        System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +219
        Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +177
        System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +173
        System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +491
```

It is no OnInit Method at based classes.
Any Ideas what I could miss?

Comment: Is the dll that contain the code deployed to your bin folder? Also, can you share the code for the custom implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error generally means that the dll does not contain the namespace defined in

```
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.ExternalLink.ExternalLinkForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

I would check the above parameter in the ExternalLink.xml also check the bin folder for the updated Dll.